# Nginx Error while making a call to server 139#6139: *11778767 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,

Tags: nginx

This is my setting for nginx server

```
 location /v1/submit{
           # First attempt to serve request as file, then
           # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
           #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           proxy_ssl_server_name on;
           proxy_pass  http://202.3.208.203:55000/cp/submitSM.jsp;
           proxy_connect_timeout 159s;
           proxy_send_timeout   600;
           proxy_read_timeout   600;
           proxy_buffer_size    64k;
           proxy_buffers     16 32k;   
           }
```

While making the call to API from nginx i am getting error as

> [error] 6139#6139: *11778767 connect() failed (111: Connection
>   refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 52.221.202.103, server:
>   _, request: "POST /v1/submit

?

Comment: See if you are connecting to the correct port and ip?

Comment: Yes i am able to connect to port. This does not happen frequently.Means  most of the time i am able to successfully process the request and sometimes it fails

Comment: look at this https://serverfault.com/a/725263

Comment: I checked and it is successfully able to connect and also there is no firewall blocking the port